# (C5) Current Pending Sector - warning

Tags: hard-drive

I know this might be already posted, but I didn't managed to find a solution..
After I read some of the questions I came to the conclusion that if that number is going up the HDD is dying :(.

I tried as recommended by an user here to run a test with HGST Windows Drive Fitness Test (WinDFT), but it can't see my drive.

Here is a screenshot of HD Tune PRO information:

[image]

What's to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the model number of your drive, this is Seagate, not HGST, which *MAY BE* why HGST diagnostic utility is not showing this drive I have a similar app that is called SeaTools (it's from Sea*gate*). It displays even my new NVMe drive.

According to various sources and [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.), pending sectors are these that weren't successfully read or written to. Outcome maybe one of these:

- the sectors can be subsequently read and return to normal pool
- the sectors can be reallocated and removed from the pool of available sectors.

Reallocated sectors (C4) value rising is a serious concern. I always write off a drive that displays either C4 or C5. Depends on the kind of data you have and how much it is valuable. I've seen a statistical research not so long ago, AFAIR from Google, that drives showing C5 are drastically more likely to completely fail in the next 6 months than normal drives.